# Using IN operator in SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the database consisting of T1 (a, b, c)
And I also have the database T2 (a, b, c)
Can I use the IN operator to check that there is a record from T1 to T2?
Like this for example:

```
select a
from T1
where (a, b, c) in (select a, b, c
                    from T2)
```

Or does the IN operator only work on a single value?
Thanks for answering :)

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: Normally it's `x in (a, b, c)`, never `(a, b, c) IN (x, y, z)` You can test for the inclusion of *one* value in a set, not overlapping sets.

Comment: ANSI SQL compliant, using the non-core feature F641, "Row and table constructors".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database.  Some databases (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, for instance) support tuples with `in`.  Others do not (SQL Server).

All databases can use `exists`:

```
select a
from T1
where exists (select 1
              from t2
              where t2.a = t1.a and t2.b = t1.b and t2.c = t1.c
             );
```

Comment: Shouldn't it say `where exists` to correctly capture the original query's intent?

Comment: @TanveerBadar . . . Yes.  Your query uses `in`, not `not in`.

Comment: Db2 does support this format of IN https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=65892628ddfca539363c31f7344d3e91  and also use of VAUES in the IN list to have literal tuples https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=119c87d76951db3dca60ffa5dbaa867c

Comment: @PaulVernon . . . I tested it with constants and it didn't work.  Alas.

Comment: Should just need the VALUES keyword. See 2nd dbfiddle  link above.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be rewritten using `exists`

```
select a
from T1 t1
where exists (select 1
                    from T2 t2 t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b and t1.c = t2.c)
```